# Export csv with string at first row and header starting at second row

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-manipulation

I want to export dataframe with special request.
I want to add string at first row and start exporting dataframe from second row.

```
# dt
col1  col2
AAA     10
BBB     50
```

For example, the string I want to add at first row is `FIRST`.
The `csv` exported data should looks like:

```
FIRST
col1,col2
AAA,10
BBB,50
```

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas can export a dataframe as csv to an already open file:

```
fd = open('file.csv', 'w')
print('FIRST', file=fd)
df.to_csv(fd, index=None)
```